# Selenium- Unable to save dynamic paths in the list..list shows 0 as size

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class DynamicXpaths {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();  
    driver.navigate().to("http://yahoo.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='UHSearchBox']")).sendKeys("selenium");
    Thread.sleep(10000);

    List<WebElement> list=  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='yui_3_12_0_1_1460454396950_758']/ul/li[starts-with(@id,'yui_3_12_0_1_1460')]/a")); 

    System.out.println(list.size());
    list.get(0).click();

}
}
```

Comment: Please provide HTML code (some of part only)

Comment: Can you tell me which element list you want? - added on behalf of "siraj"

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to find a dynamically generated id using a static string. Everytime you go to the page 'yui_3_12_0_1_1460454396950_758' and 'yui_3_12_0_1_1460' will change. You have to find another way to find them.

Answer (score 0):

As Per my understanding you script is following steps :

1. Open yahoo
2. Search selenium
3. Get list of links which are present in More link

So get list of elements(links)

```
List<WebElement> list=  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='yui3-menu-content']/ul/li/a"));
```

Note : Further step that you perform is to click on first link so for that folow this step.

```
driver.findElements(By.id("yucs-more-link")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
list.get(0).click();
```

Let me know If any query.

Comment: Can I know why this answer is down voted ?

Comment: I think your xpath is not working so it may be down voted.

Comment: Which error you have found ?

Comment: You are not point to auto complete seachText box and instead the top link and More (top menu) and the question is in search text box

Answer (score 0):

As the list is shown in iframe so you need to switch to iframe first then try to find out the elements.

[image]

so your code should be

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='sa-shim']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

List<WebElement> list=  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='yui_3_12_0_1_1460454396950_758']/ul/li[starts-with(@id,'yui_3_12_0_1_1460')]/a"));
```

Comment: I believe, the search list not under iframe and the xpath you provide is invalid as id element is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fetch the list using class parameter using CSS selector. Please try to use the below code instead of xpath.

```
By.cssSelector(".sa-panel.sa-gossip .sa-item")
```